# cant ssh into git: PTY allocation request failed on channel 0

Tags: git, ssh, rsa, pty

I'm trying to update homebrew but i cant connect to git..
i see the https isnt getting through and when i try to ssh -t i get :
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
these are my results form ssh -v:

```
klein@MacBook-Pro .ssh % ssh -v git@github.com
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/klein/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/klein/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /users/klein/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /users/klein/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-42834f78
debug1: no match: babeld-42834f78
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/klein/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key:  RSA SHA256:FtOwFwwlGSFpdkdM+Po6Yv5CUrgfxPND9Aq/b575NdI agent
debug1: Will attempt key: klein@MacBook-Pro.localdomain RSA SHA256:9hkiUuvWfFm6hbf5l3zsBBIF6MAQkpeAah3ukcq0cOA agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /users/klein/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:tFpBa6n3n4eB4KtqUFy0dvj3xWnURehYvdB5tr6BbJQ explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key:  RSA SHA256:FtOwFwwlGSFpdkdM+Po6Yv5CUrgfxPND9Aq/b575NdI agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: klein@MacBook-Pro.localdomain RSA SHA256:9hkiUuvWfFm6hbf5l3zsBBIF6MAQkpeAah3ukcq0cOA agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /users/klein/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:tFpBa6n3n4eB4KtqUFy0dvj3xWnURehYvdB5tr6BbJQ explicit
debug1: Server accepts key: /users/klein/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:tFpBa6n3n4eB4KtqUFy0dvj3xWnURehYvdB5tr6BbJQ explicit
Enter passphrase for key '/users/klein/.ssh/id_rsa': 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([140.82.112.4]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi kippelicious! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to github.com closed.
Transferred: sent 4208, received 2672 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 17817.7, received 11313.9
debug1: Exit status 1
```

I already deleted my entire .ssh folder, installed fresh ssh keys but nothing is working.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Read the message: "Hi kippelicious! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access."

Comment: It's `ssh -T` (uppercase T), which tells ssh *don't bother with pty allocation*, that suppresses the error message you saw. (Lowercase t tells ssh *do pty allocation even if you think you don't need it*, which guarantees the error.) However, that error message is irrelevant, as @Mat noted: your test actually succeeded.

Comment: Also, GitHub is not Git; it's a repository hosting service that also provides a web-based interface to those repositories.

Answer (score 4):

A better test would be:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Then you would see only:

```
Hi kippelicious! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

That way, you know you can start using SSH URL like `git@github.com:<me>/<my repo>`

Answer (score 1):

This error has happened to me as well because of the small **t**
When I tried `ssh -T git@github.com` it did work